# When using eventListeners why use event.target instead of just referencing the element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, target

If I have a bunch of buttons in HTML and run:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(btn.textContent);
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  });
});
```

What is the difference between btn and e.target? I know I could use event delegation to make this cleaner but, want to know if these are the exact same and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Both are just references to the same object. There is no difference other than the way you're refering them. But, you only have access to the `btn` variable inside the loop. `event.target` is available regardless of the scope of the event handler callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Answer (score 0):

They may be different. `event.target` is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched. This may not be the same object as the element which the listener is attached to. `event.target` could be a child element which bubbled the event up to the DOM element which has the listener attached.

On the other hand, `event.currentTarget` is a reference to the object which has the listener attached and can be used interchangeably.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget